# Controlling my TECO air conditioner with my Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor

I have an aircon unit in my house. I want to be able to control it using my Raspberry Pi.
The unit comes with an infrared remote. Please note that I am a seasoned software engineer, so the software side doesn't scare me. However, I am also particularly helpless with anything hardware-related.

What I need to do is this:

1. Figure out what the remote *actually* sends out. How do I do that? By reverse-engineering how it works, my understanding is that the remote sends a *full* packet of data that includes mode (Cool/Heat), temperature, and fan speed. To know what is sent to the unit, I will need a receiver and actually dump the data. I assume I will be able to reverse-engineer whatever was sent after a few trials.
2. Actually send the right impulses to the unit. Once I know what the data is, I will be able to send the right infrared information to the aircon unit.

Here is my plan:

(1)
Buy these:

- https://core-electronics.com.au/dht22-temperature-and-humidity-sensor.html  DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Sensor
- https://core-electronics.com.au/digital-ir-transmitter-module-arduino-compatible.html DIGITAL IR Transmitter Module
- https://core-electronics.com.au/digital-ir-receiver-module-arduino-compatible.html Digital IR Receiver Module(Arduino Compatible)

(2)
Use the receiver to figure out what data is sent by the remote when changing temperature/mode etc.

(3)
Use the transmitter to send the proper data to the aircon unit

(4) Use the temperature sensor to send the right commands to the aircon unit

(5) Write my own software which will control the air con sending the correct request to the unit depending on the recorded temperature

Am I on the right track? Or am I totally wasting my money by doing this?

Comment: Start with sensor and transmitter.  If you have a programmable remote, you could try that too.  Some phones have the capability too.  Once you are confident that you can replicate the signal, then move on.  If you can't then consider buying a spare remote and wiring your pi to that.

Comment: Wait I am not sure I follow... so my plan is good? I don't want to use a phone as I am not good at writing phone apps. I didn't think about hacking an existing remote, but surely it would be harder than sending the right IR signals?

Comment: the "right" IR signals may be encrypted in some way

Comment: Oh wait what...? Is it common for them to encrypt IR signals? Surely...

Comment: Thing is we just don't know.  Your plan has the potential to fail.  Surefire plan is to have a pi control a contraption that presses the working remote instead of a person.  Try stuff to figure out what might work if you are risk averse.